# How can I create multiple account in Azure AD B2C with unique username but allowing same email address?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to create multiple user account in Azure AD B2C with unique usernames but same email address. The user logins with the username.

**Scenario**

I have an e-commerce b2b site.
A user reseller has an account on the b2b site with unique username and an email address.
The same user has another different account on the same b2b site with a different (unique) username but he has the same email address.
So you have:

- **account1**: username is **Username1** and email is **matt@pippo.com**
- **account2**: username is **Username2** and email is **matt@pippo.com**

For the password reset you need both the username and the email.

Is this scenario supported on Azure AD B2C?

Suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

This username sample already accomplished this:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin

The username, or login identifier, is stored in the signInNames.username attribute. This has a uniqueness constraint.

The email is stored in the strongAuthenticationEmailAddress attribute, which does not have a uniqueness constraint. You could swap it for an extension attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method  theoretically. This requires you to set up different account types for this email address. For example, if you have a gmail account, you can directly register to B2C as a local account, or you can configure gmail as a Identity providers, if you log in with gmail, this achieves two identical mailboxes but different account names.

However, this method is not recommended. This is equivalent to two completely different account types. If you require both **account1** and **account2** to be local accounts, then obviously this method will not work. Therefore, in summary, I don’t think you can create two different user accounts with the same email address.